# How to improve GCP's Speech to Text API results for two persons conversation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, transcription

I need some library or API which will map a audio and manually transcribed text so that I can get the timestamps for each word. Tried using GCP to transcribe and get the timestamps but its error rate is to too much and the manual work is increased. The audio files are conversations between doctor and patient so the patient voice is not very audible. I guess that is why GCP is not able to transcribe it correctly.

Ideally I would like to decrease the manual work and get accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools in GCP's Speech to Text API that you can potentially use to improve your results:

- Use their [enhanced models](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enhanced-models). There is one optimized for phone calls that can fit this scenario as it is a two person conversation.
- You can use [speaker diarization](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices) to detect who is speaking in which moment. With that information you can preprocess your audio file and increase the volume in the parts where the patient is speaking.
- Check [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-time-offsets) to get word timestamps.